# addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL -> NSString parameter?

Tags: ios, nsstring, backup, icloud

In order to follow the Data Storage Guidelines I must use the below method to add a flag to say to not back it up to iCloud. However, the parameter here is for a NSURL. I need to pass it a NSString like from a line like so

```
return [[self offlineQueuePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SHKOfflineQueue.plist"];
```

Here is the method that takes in a URL.

```
    - (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
{
    if (&NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey == nil) { // iOS <= 5.0.1
        const char* filePath = [[URL path] fileSystemRepresentation];

        const char* attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
        u_int8_t attrValue = 1;

        int result = setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
        return result == 0;
    } else { // iOS >= 5.1
        NSError *error = nil;
        [URL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];
        return error == nil;
    }
}
```

**Anyway, how would I modify the method above to achieve the same while taking in a NSString as a parameter?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to modify the method. Convert your string to URL.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your string"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method

```
 NSURL *pathURL113= [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Your string]];
```

this is perfect code.